# wordpress get_excerpt() in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

**UPDATE: I found a work around, LISTED BELOW.** I am new to wordpress as of today. I can't seem to get "the_excerpt" in this loop. It  either does not show or posts on the first one. Any ideas?

It's towards the very bottom where I am trying to insert it.

```
<?
if(!$_GET[id])
{
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    start_wp();
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 33, 33);

        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        { ?>

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="blogHolder">
  <tr>
    <td width="21%" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><div class="blogImage"><? echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], array(133,133) ); ?></div>      <img src="images/blogImageBox.png" width="177" height="177" /></td>
    <td width="79%" height="23" valign="middle" class="blogTitle"><? echo $recent["post_title"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="24" valign="middle" class="blogTitle"><? echo $excerpt; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    </tr>
</table>


<? } 


    }
}/// End if no ID
?>
```

**UPDATE: I found a work around.**

```
<?
if(!$_GET[id])
{


$posts = get_posts();

foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>


        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="blogHolder">
  <tr>
    <td width="21%" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><div class="blogImage"><? echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], array(133,133) ); ?></div>      <img src="images/blogImageBox.png" width="177" height="177" /></td>
    <td width="79%" height="23" valign="middle" class="blogTitle"><? echo the_title(); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="24" valign="top" ><blockquote class="blogContent">
      <p><? echo the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </blockquote></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    </tr>
</table>


<?php
endforeach;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Loop Syntax, `wp_start();` is deprecated since 1.5.

```
if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  //Display my single post title
  the_title();

  //Display post thumbnail image
  if( has_thumbnail ) : the_post_thumbnail();

  //Display post excerpt
  the_excerpt();

endwhile; endif;
```

You can run your own query using [`WP_Query Class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Note:
If you will use one or more Loop in the same page remember to `wp_reset_postdata();`

```
//Set up array of arguments, please check WP_Query/get_posts() docs please
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '5' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_posts();
//Display my single post title
  the_title();

  //Display post thumbnail image
  if( has_thumbnail ) : the_post_thumbnail();

  //Display post excerpt
  the_excerpt();

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Hope it helps!